# Append Data in a Big Query Table Automatically from Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have some excel files that i want to append to a Big Query table. After doing that i want to append data to the same Big Query table using cloud storage automatically thru a scheduler which runs 4 times a day. How to do this. Please keep in mind i am not a developer. I just know SQL and Big Query.

Comment: How does the data get into Google Cloud Storage and how do you know the names of the files? Are you pushing the data 4 times a day? If so, can you extend whatever script you are using to push the data to also kick off the load jobs in BigQuery?

Comment: Michael...i am getting the files uploaded manually to the cloud storage.....i am not using any script as i am poor in the high level scripting....i just know BQ.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest write a simple script and host it Google App Engine, and register a bucket notification and hook it with that GAE endpoint.

Whenever a file is upload to the bucket, GAE will be notificated, and invoke your script, which then gets the file, extract the info from it, and append to the table you specify in Big Query.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Watching